# Angular 7 - WARNING in Circular dependency detected:

Tags: angular, typescript

All of a sudden I started getting it. Here are two warnings I am getting at the end of ng serve:

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\_services\ignore-interceptor.service.ts -> 
src\app\_services\index.ts -> src\app\_services\ignore- 
interceptor.service.ts

WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\_services\index.ts -> src\app\_services\ignore- 
interceptor.service.ts -> src\app\_services\index.ts
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
```

My code fragments are:

ignore-interceptor.service.ts

```
import { UserService } from '../_services';
...
...
```

index.ts:

```
export * from './alert.service';
export * from './authentication.service';
export * from './user.service';
export * from './ignore-interceptor.service'
```

If I remove import { UserService } from '../_services'; in ignore-interceptor.service.ts then I am not getting warnings.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: yes when u import the service in another serviuce that is in the same index.ts then u have to explicitly import them by name

Comment: ur import should be ```import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service';``` instead of ```import { UserService } from '../_services```

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to avoid a circular dependency warning in such a case where you import services in other services that are exported by the same index.ts, you have to import the specific dependency explicitly by name.

Like so:

```
import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service';
```

Instead of:

```
import { UserService } from '../_services';
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Generally circuler dependency arises when you use `index.ts` file to export services. And import services in another services  thats are exported in the same `index.ts` file.

Like you are importing `UserService` from `index.ts`( where `UserService` has been exported from `user-servce` ) file in `ignore-interceptor.service`, at the same time exporting both '''user-service''' and `ignore-interceptor.service` in `index.ts` file.

Here your circuler dependency has been created -

`ignore-interceptor.service → index.ts → ignore-interceptor.service`

So in that case you need to import services from absolute path rather from `index.ts` file. Like -

`import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service';`

Better i will recommend not using index.ts for exporting and importing services.

This is also true for using `index.ts` for exporting and importing components, models or any classes.

Comment: Why would you recommend not to use index.ts files?

Comment: Because sometimes we export classes in index.ts file without keeping in mind that circular dependency.